# How to fill in missing times in R from next and previous date time?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

I want to use a way where I can successfully match values for 'checks' which have no start and end times. At first I thought to use bilinear interpolation for this task, but then i thought that's too much complicated and rather I just need something very similar.

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B),
                 "Check"= c(1:5),
                 "Start_time" = c("start_a1","start_a2","start_a3","start_a4","start_a5","startb1","startb2","startb3",NA,"startb5"),
                 "end_time" = c("end_a1","end_a2","end_a3","end_a4","end_a5","end_b1","end_b2",NA,NA,"endb5")
                 )
```

so what I am ideally looking for any check which has missing start time and end time it should pick data from the next check's start time, not previous.

I am trying the following code block but its giving me an issue:

```
df$end_time[df$check==3 & is.na(df_main$end_time)]] <- df$start_time[df$check==5]

#this gives a length issue
```

Any advice would be helpful here, my dataset contains approx 5k rows, and each ID has a number of checks with start time and end time.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: hello, actually i wanted to copy paste the dataframe but i just couldn't let me post it as code

Comment: i added a data frame code for sample data

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyr` package has a function `fill()` which does exactly this.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(c(Start_time,end_time),.direction='up')

# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
   ID    Check Start_time end_time
   <chr> <int> <chr>      <chr>   
 1 A         1 start_a1   end_a1  
 2 A         2 start_a2   end_a2  
 3 A         3 start_a3   end_a3  
 4 A         4 start_a4   end_a4  
 5 A         5 start_a5   end_a5  
 6 B         1 startb1    end_b1  
 7 B         2 startb2    end_b2  
 8 B         3 startb3    endb5   
 9 B         4 startb5    endb5   
10 B         5 startb5    endb5
```

The `.direction="up"` parameter means it takes the next non-missing value to fill in blanks. To use the previous value you would use `.direction="down"`. And using `.direction="updown"` would use the next value unless there are no more non-missing values in that group, then it would take the previous non-missing value. (Useful in cases where the missing value is the last row of the group.)

Comment: thanks this helped a lot. Appreciate your help.